# What is the preferable way to get the I/O of another console program in Perl?

Tags: perl

It seems there are 2 ways to get the I/O of another program in Perl, one is surround the program with arguments by **`**, the other is using `open` like below, any difference between these 2 and which one is preferred?

```
# 2 options to get the I/O of another program
1. $output = `program`;
2. open(PIPE, 'program |');
```

Comment: These are not the only ways. E.g. when using `open`, always use [the multiple argument version](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) and pass the command arguments as a list, if you can, to avoid unnecessarily shell invocation and interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipes are useful when you want to read output from a process over time. Let's say you want to monitor a log file.

You can, for example, write:

```
open(PIPE, 'tail -f log.txt |');

while (<PIPE>) {
    chomp;
    print("NEW LINE: $_\n");
}
```

and do some action on every new line added to the log.

If you were to write:

```
$output = `tail -f log.txt`;
println($output);
```

Then your program would never actually get to the println part since a command in backticks will wait until the command has returned.

Answer (score 2):

Your 2nd case appears to be piping *to* 'program', rather than receiving input from it.

If you mean (and I think you do):

```
open(PIPE, "program |")
```

then the advantage of piping in is that you can process record-by-record, and you don't consume the whole of the process's output in one go (as occurs in the first scenario). That would be better from a memory perspective, and possbily from a time perspective if the program runs over a long period.

A possibility is to pipe from `stdin`, and then you can organise your pipes on the command line, and provide additional filtering etc. if required, and not hardcode a dependency on a particular binary.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different ways of communicating between processes in perl - so many that there's a whole section of documentation on it [`perlipc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html)

For simple requirements, it doesn't really matter what you use. I would say - use whatever's most obvious given the context.

If you're just running a command and grabbing the output as a block:

```
my $df_out = `df -h`;
```

Then I consider backticks most appropriate.

If you're wanting to do line by line parsing - backticks *will* work, but generally I'll prefer an `open`.

E.g.

```
open ( my $ssh_data, "-|", "ssh -n $hostname df" );
my %size_of;
while ( <$ssh_data> ) { 
    my ( $fs, $total, $used, $avail ) = split;
    $size_of{$fs} = $total;
}
close ( $ssh_data );
```

`IPC::Open2` and `IPC::Open3` are also options to allow bidirectional communication.

One caveat though - I'd strongly recommend *not* using 2 argument open, and using lexical filehandles. It's a good habit to train yourself in - even if it doesn't matter *now* getting used to 3-arg open is worth doing.